# Отсутствует пункт меню "Профили и управление устройством" на iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Запускаю проект на эмуляторе, все работает нормально.

Пытаюсь запустить на реальном устройстве, выдает сообщение, данное приложение от несертифицированного разработчика

Ну и после чего предлагает в настройках системы необходимо дать разрешение на запуск приложения.

Иду в настройки, но в настройках **отсутствует** пункт меню: ***Профили и управление устройством***.

Я так понимаю, что данный пункт меню появляется только в том случае, если в систему загружен профиль (сертификат). Т.е. значит сейчас при установке сертификат не устанавливается? Но почему, и как исправить это?

Comment: Неужели поиск по настройкам тоже ничего не дал?

Comment: Данный пункт меню появляется только в том случае, если установлен какой либо профиль. Мне в итоге удалось запустить приложение, но для этого пришлось сменить профиль своего проекта

Answer (score 2):

Мне удалось запустить приложение, только после того, как я поменял профиль своего проекта в поле Bundle Identifier.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206143/ios-untrusted-developer-error-when-testing-app